My rendering image is different than the camera view
So, yeah, I did the hole camera to view shtick but is still different



Looks like you have a keyframe set on your camera, its possible that you've moved the camera's position without updating or saving the new keyframe. Try changing what frame on the timeline you're on to see if it updates and moves.

I dont really know how to do that
Update:

You can use the arrow keys or click and drag on the timeline to change the current selected frame. When you're done, select the camera in its correct position and press I to set a keyframe for its position and rotation
